# Hydropneumatic suspension ride height

Tags: suspension

My Citroën BX has various ride heights since it works on hydropneumatic suspension.

How safe / smart would it be to drive using the lowest height VS the medium ride height? pics for comparison [image]

Comment: Define "smart" and/or "safe ... this is a very subjective question. I would assume, Citroën designed it to be safe at either (or any, for that matter) ride height, or they'd be leaving themselves open for lawsuits.

Comment: Yup + it's down to comfort, not safety

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer my own question since I recieved some help from a Xantia driver.

The lowest syspension setting turns off the system and leaves your car with 0 suspension wich is highly unrecommended.

It's inteded for servicing and liquid flushing.

On the other hand higher ride heights can be used to drive although the highest setting is exclusively for low speeds and clearing obstacles.